# Completed campaign, but still don't have access to restricted area?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've completed the main campaign, but I still can't access the restricted area. I want to earn the Gotham Base Jumper achievement.

What am I missing? If it's relevant, I'm running on Mac OS X.

Comment: Are you trying to access the Restricted Area from the elevator, or from the city?

Answer (score 2):

There is never a way to access the Restricted Area by walking, gliding, nor fancy Batman moves from the city. In order to return to the Wonder Tower, you must get there the same way you have before, through the subway.

Once you get to the top of Wonder Tower, don't just jump off. This achievement is more difficult to get then it might seem since the game doesn't allow you to go all the way to the ground and will force Batman to grapple up and ruin your glide. My favorite method to continue the glide is to dive-bomb and pull out repeatedly to recover lost altitude. If you've completed the AR training, you should be familiar with this approach.